# Tkinter - Entry created with Loop, how can I interact with individual entries?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, widget

I have this code to display many entries.
**I have no problem to get individually the data that the user enters thanks to the list.**

But If I want, for example to disable or clear only one of the entry (through a button, or function or whatever) and not all, how can I interact with ONLY the concerned entry ?

```
import os
from tkinter import *

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("800x635")

user_entries=[]
nbofcalc=9
a=0
b=1

for x in range(nbofcalc):
    cadre1=Frame(fenetre)
    cadre1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
    cadre=Frame(cadre1)
    cadre.pack()
    c=str(b)
    calc=Label(cadre,text="Calculation "+c+"  ")
    calc.pack(side=LEFT)
    my_entry=Entry(cadre, bd=5)
    my_entry.pack(side=LEFT)
    user_entries.append(my_entry)
    a+=1
    b+=1
  

fenetre.mainloop()
os.system("pause")
```

[image]

Comment: You can interact with any single `Entry` you wish via its element in the `user_entries` list. i.e. `user_entries[2]`

Comment: Just tried, it works. I remember having tried without success. Don't know what I did wrong then.
Thank you !!